# How to modify subList without ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list, sublist

I have a little problem with `ListIterator`.

I have started iterate original list `[1, 4, 5]`, I am between `1` and `4`. Then I modify list to the `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Now I would like to iterate rest of the original list. Here I give an example code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();  // []
        list.add(new Integer(1));  // [1]
        list.add(new Integer(4));  // [1, 4]
        list.add(new Integer(5));  // [1, 4, 5]
        ListIterator<Integer> iterator = (ListIterator<Integer>) list.iterator();

        System.out.println(iterator.next()); // prints [1]

        // modify subList
        List<Integer> subList = list.subList(0, 2);    // [1, 4]
        subList.add(1, new Integer(2));    // [1, 2, 4]
        subList.add(2, new Integer(3));    // [1, 2, 3, 4]

        // need to print rest of oryginal list: [4, 5]
        while (iterator.hasNext())
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

When I'm executing it I have got java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. Do you have any idea how can I do it correctly?

Comment: You can't modify something while you're iterating over it. You'll have to make a copy to modify and iterate over the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the modifications to the list through the iterator (instead of through the list) then you won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
    System.out.println(iterator.next()); // prints [1]

    iterator.add(new Integer(2)); // [1, 2, 4]
    iterator.add(new Integer(3)); // [1, 2, 3, 4]

    while (iterator.hasNext())
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

Comment: 2 and 3 will be skipped automatically. From the docs about [ListIterator#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)):  "The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to previous would return the new element."

Comment: When I'm modifying subList, I don't have access to the original iterator.

Comment: @WojciechKo In that case another option is to use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) - it returns iterators on snapshots, so they'll never throw `ConcurrentModificationExceptions`.  Another option is to use a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) - its iterators are weakly consistent, and will never throw `ConcurrentModificationExceptions`

Comment: @WojciechKo Or you can use a [ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList.htm), whose iterators are also weakly consistent

Answer (score 7):

You've misunderstood the usage of [`list.subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29).

The sublist is simply a view of a portion of the original list. If you modify the sublist, you're really modifying the original list.

What you want, is to copy part of the original list:

```
List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.subList(0,2));
```